# Como posso gerar uma key de 7 caracteres alfa-numerico?

Tags: php

Como poderei gerar uma key com 7 caracteres alfa-numéricos, completamente aleatória em PHP?

Ou seja quero fazer uma key com números e letras maiusculas completamente aleatórias.

Já experimentei utilizar o rand, porem o rand só me gerar números.

Comment: `strtoupper(substr(md5(date("YmdHis")), 1, 7));`

Comment: É isso mesmo William, mas como faço para colocar as letras em maiusculas?

Comment: Opá ! acabei editando meu comentário e adicionei a função `strtoupper`

Comment: Obrigado.! Já tinha visto no google essa function entretanto mas muito obrigado pela ajuda, se quiser poste como resposta, para dar cotação.

Comment: Acredito que a sugestão do William não responde totalmente a pergunta, uma vez que isso não é aleatório, como solicitado em "completamente aleatórias". Isso está a fazer um MD5() baseado na data atual. Em outras palavras é possível adivinhar o código uma vez que apenas captura os 7 primeiros caracteres do MD5 da data. Ele aperece ser aleatório pois sempre possui "um segundo" diferente, gerando assim um novo MD5, porém tempo não é aleatório. Além disso se usar o date() para a data/hora de Brasília/BR, irá ocorrer colisão quando sair/entrar do horário de verão, afinal o tempo irá se repetir. :S

Comment: Apenas esteja ciente de que aleatório não significa único. Gerar código aleatório dentro da condição proposta é simples. O complicado é gerar strings únicas. Note que que encriptar com MD5, conforme exemplo que postaram e cortar a string final é bastante inseguro pois aumenta exponencialmente as colisões.

Comment: Se a pergunta com 4 votos responde à pergunta, seria legal colocar a tag [tag:php-7]

Answer (score 12):

O método mais seguro para gerar um combinação pseudo-aleatoria é usando o `random_bytes()`.

Dessa forma utilize da seguinte forma:

```
$numero_de_bytes = 4;

$restultado_bytes = random_bytes($numero_de_bytes);
$resultado_final = bin2hex($restultado_bytes);
```

Isso irá gerar uma combinação de 8 caracteres, pseudo-randomicos.

Para passar para maiúsculo utilize o `strtoupper`, como `strtoupper($resultado final)`. Para remover um dos caracteres, afim de torna-lo com 7 ao invés de 8, utilize o `substr()`, dessa forma `substr($resultado_final, 1)`.

Resultando em:

```
$resultado_final = strtoupper(substr(bin2hex(random_bytes(4)), 1));
```

> Essa função está disponível no PHP 7 (e superior), para usa-lo em versões antiga veja [nesta implementação](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat).

Comment: Atualmente vamos em que versão do PHP?

Comment: A última versão é a 7.0.8.

Comment: Vou testar, um momento.

Answer (score 5):

## `sprintf` e `mt_rand`

Uma outra opção curta e simples seria combinando `mt_rand`com `sprintf`.

```
sprintf('%07X', mt_rand(0, 0xFFFFFFF))
```

No caso, vou explicar:

`mt_rand` gerará um número de 0 até `0xFFFFFFF` (que equivale a um int 268435455).

`sprintf` formata um valor de acordo com um parâmetro específico. Usei no caso o modificador `%X`, que formata um valor para um número hexadecimal (o X maiúsculo significa que as letras serão maiúsculas, se quiser minúsculas pode usar `%x`).Porém, antes do `X` há um número `7`. Isso significa que o valor que será formatado no segundo parâmetro de `sprintf` deverá conter `7` caracteres ou mais. E por fim, o `0` antes do `7` significa que, quando não tiver 7 caracteres, será preenchido com `0`.

Então, curtamente explicando:

```
'%' - curinga do modificador
`0` - o número a ser preenchido quando faltar
`7` - quantidade especificada para formatação
`X` - formatada para hexadecimal, com letras maiúsculas (pode ser trocado para `x`)
```

## `str_shuffle`, `str_repeat` e `substr`

A função `str_shuffle` do PHP tem como finalidade misturar uma determinada `string`. Com inteligência aplicada, você poderá também produzir bons resultados por meio da mesma.

No meu exemplo, criei uma lista de caracteres de `a` a `z` e `0` a `9`.
Usei `str_repeat` para repetir a lista de caracteres. Em seguida usei `substr` para reduzir a `7`.

Exemplo:

```
    $ascii = implode('', array_merge(range('a', 'z'), range(0, 9)));

    $ascii = str_repeat($ascii, 5);

    substr(str_shuffle($ascii), 0, 7);
```

Você também pode utilizar uma função chamada `random_bytes`, mas talvez você tenha que trabalhar com conversões de valores, já que os valores retornados pela mesma são caracteres que vão além do alfa-numérico. Você pode especificar através do primeiro parâmetro quantos bytes você quer:

```
     openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(7) // dJ─Å(\x01"
```

Uma última opção seria usar `dechex(mt_rand(0, 0xfffffff))`

Answer (score 4):

Aqui está outra alternativa para gerar uma string pseudo-aleatória com 7 caracteres, inclui maiusculas, minusculas, e numeros:

```
$upper = implode('', range('A', 'Z')); // ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
$lower = implode('', range('a', 'z')); // abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzy
$nums = implode('', range(0, 9)); // 0123456789

$alphaNumeric = $upper.$lower.$nums; // ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
$string = '';
$len = 7; // numero de chars
for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
    $string .= $alphaNumeric[rand(0, strlen($alphaNumeric) - 1)];
}
echo $string; // ex: q02TAq3
```

Answer (score 4):

Há um tempo eu cheguei a essa função:

```
function generateRandomString($size = 7){
   $chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyz0123456789";
   $randomString = '';
   for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i = $i+1){
      $randomString .= $chars[mt_rand(0,60)];
   }
   return $randomString;
}
```

Comment: Simples função, porém bem funcional. Excelente!

Answer (score -2):

```html
<?php
    function chaveAlfaNumerica($QuantidadeDeCaracteresDaChave){
        $res = implode('', range('A', 'z')); // ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxiz
        $con = 1;
        $var = '';
        while($con < $QuantidadeDeCaracteresDaChave ){
            $n = rand(0, 57); 
            if (($n == 26) || ($n == 27) || ($n == 28) || ($n == 29) || ($n == 30) || ($n == 31)){
        }else{
            $var = $var.$n.$res[$n];
            $con++;
            }
        }
        return substr($var, 0, $QuantidadeDeCaracteresDaChave);
        }
        //chamando a função.
        echo chaveAlfaNumerica(3);
        //retorna a chave com a quantidade passada no parametro.
?>
```

Eu criei esta função que cria uma chave aleatória em php,